# Read Binary Json from Qt QJsonDocument::toBinaryData using non-Qt?

Tags: python, c++, json, qt, jsoncpp

I have the following JSON structure:

```
"{
    "dateTime": "02/06/2016 - 13:01:06",
    "event": 12344,
    "eventOwner": "1",
    "condition": "",
    "ownerParent": "",
    "sn": "0000000000"
}"
```

I write this as binary file header/watermark, using Qt framework QJsonDocument::toBinaryData() function.

However, I am unable to parse it back from python and/or standard c++ in order use the JSON again.

it appears Qt also writes a header on this binary data, tagging "qbjs1", then the rawData (Qt Binary JSON version 1).

However, there's some '\0' which turns to be impossible to parse the binary data to JSON. As the following:

the hexdump from the JSON binary data:

```
00000000  71 62 6a 73 01 00 00 00  c0 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00  |qbjs............|
00000010  a8 00 00 00 9b 03 00 00  08 00 64 61 74 65 54 69  |..........dateTi|
00000020  6d 65 00 00 15 00 30 32  2f 30 36 2f 32 30 31 36  |me....02/06/2016|
00000030  20 2d 20 31 33 3a 30 31  3a 30 36 00 1a f3 02 00  | - 13:01:06.....|
00000040  06 00 65 76 65 6e 74 1b  0d 00 00 07 00 65 76 65  |..event......eve|
00000050  6e 74 4f 77 6e 65 72 00  00 00 08 00 31 00 00 1b  |ntOwner.....1...|
00000060  0e 00 00 0b 00 63 6f 6e  64 69 74 69 6f 6e 00 00  |.....condition..|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 1b 10 00  00 06 00 6f 77 6e 65 72  |...........owner|
00000080  50 61 72 65 6e 74 0b 00  34 35 20 66 6f 72 6b 65  |Parent..45 forke|
00000090  64 00 00 00 9b 13 00 00  05 00 73 6e 00 0d 00 30  |d.........sn...0|
000000a0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 0c 00 00 00 34 00 00  |000000000....4..|
000000b0  00 40 00 00 00 5c 00 00  00 74 00 00 00 90 00 00  |.@...\...t......|
000000c0  00 0d                                             |..|
000000c2
```

How could I parse this binary data with non-QT C++ and python?

Comment: docs: *The binary representation is also the **native format used internally in Qt**, and is very efficient and fast to convert to and from.* Saying that it is internal means that you can change from version to version without prior notice, so there is no single way to do it, it is similar to what happens with QDataStream.

Comment: Since this is not a standard format, but an idiosyncratic format unique to Qt, there's a good chance there are no non-Qt libraries to parse it. If the format is documented somewhere, you could write one yourself based on that documentation. If not, you could reverse engineer it by reading the Qt source, but that might put you under the obligations of their license, or you could reverse engineer it from first principles.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write a trivial tool that uses Qt to stream in Qt-binary-JSON and stream out real JSON and vice-versa, and just pipe data through that tool from a non-Qt C++ or Python program?

Comment: By the way, as far as I can tell from a quick scan, the `\0` bytes are mostly there to pad things out so that everything but strings is at a a fixed-or-easily-computable offset. Which is presumably what makes it "not as space efficient… but much faster to access".

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a standard format, but an idiosyncratic format unique to Qt, there are probably no non-Qt libraries to parse it.

Furthermore, because it's undocumented and internal, there's no guarantees that it'll even be the same from version to version of Qt.<sup>1</sup>

If you're willing to read the Qt source code (make sure that doesn't put any license restrictions on you that you don't want), the format seems to be documented pretty well in [`src/corelib/serialization/qjson_p.h`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/serialization/qjson_p.h). So, you could write your own parser for this format. You could even borrow source code from the rest of that `serialization` directory to do most of the work.

Otherwise, the only option is to reverse engineer it by looking at a variety JSON and Qt-binary-JSON equivalents and figuring out how each kind of value gets stored. (It can't be too complex; there isn't *that* much to JSON…)

---

<sub>1. In fact, the documentation in the source has a large explicit warning: "This file is not part of the Qt API.  It exists purely as an implementation detail.  This header file may change from version to version without notice, or even be removed."</sub>